# Display the last bit after a binary addition

Tags: c++, binary

I'm trying to add two binary digits. The output is fine except the last bit. The last bit is not displayed as seen in the picture below the code. Does anybody know what's wrong here?

```
int main(){
char C[9]={'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
char B[9]={'0','1','0','0','0','0','0','1','\0'};
char A[9]={'0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','\0'};
char sum[9]={'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
char carry='0';

for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {    
    C[i] = (A[i] ^ B[i]) ^ carry;
    carry = A[i] & B[i];
}
cout << A << endl << B << endl << C << endl;    //output shown below

//for wrap-around carry
for(int i = 7; carry!=0; i--) {
    sum[i] = C[i] ^ carry;
    carry = C[i] & carry;
}
 return 0;
 }
```

[image: Shows the output, the last digit is missing.]

Comment: I think your algorithm misses the possibility of a repeated carry. Consider `001 + 011`. There are two carries, not one.

Comment: what is `sum` defined as?

Comment: Hmm. The posted code seems to work when I run it on ideone. http://ideone.com/PewJPt Although the input is different than displayed here.

Comment: Tested the code you provided, it works as expected. The output shown is incorrect, except if you missed a part of the code to be posted.

Comment: @MSalters yeah :( it misses the carry in case sum is 3. thanks for pointing out. will implement again =(

Comment: @patchwork same char array

Comment: @Raxvan no its the whole program

Comment: This is not the whole program. There is no main() and where is sum[] defined

Comment: @drescherjm whatever input i give the last bit is always missing after executing

Comment: You should do your cout after your variable C has been calculated.

Comment: your code worked ok for me ( after you edited it to include `sum` and `main()`). Are you positive that the code you're running is the same as the code you posted?

Comment: @drescherjm yeah i had calculated C first and then printed the value

Comment: I guess I should have said you are not printing sum.

Comment: @patchwork yup its the full code now

Comment: @drescherjm will it make any difference? as C is already calculated anh has no role in second step

Comment: The interesting thing is the output you posted is wrong for A. I mean A = 01000000 not 01000001 using the code you posted.

Comment: @drescherjm it was because after taking image i was changing the input so check whether its not working with this input one only or for with other values as well

Comment: @sara Your code for the wrap around carry calculation is wrong. And it invokes undefined behavior by going outside the bounds of sum. This is the reason why the code worked for me I was not including that since you did not define or output sum. In that loop there is no stopping i from being -1 or even lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at [the full Adder algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Full_adder). This shows how to sum binary numbers and calculate the carry.

Also, if you are using numbers greater than 0 always, I'd suggest you to use `unsigned char`.

Now, here's an example of how sum should work following the full Adder work :

```
for(i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
   C[i] = ((A[i] ^ B[i]) ^ carry); 
   carry = ((A[i] & B[i]) | (A[i] & carry)) | (B[i] & carry); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't adding two digits in a binary operation.

Instead of this, your are using strings.

If you use int for your values you can use binary operators. like "&"

`myVar & 1` will give you the least bit.

Comment: The homework assignment probably requires using c strings. Although the OP should clarify.

Comment: no i tried using int arrays but the output i got wasn't integer was in hexadecimal :(

Comment: hexadecimal means you printed the address of the array not its contents.